# TC++PL 4th Ed, C++ {}-list Implementation model

Tags: c++, c++11

The section $11.3 (Lists) is a bit confusing to me.

Quoting the book,

> The implementation model for {}-lists comes in three parts: 
> • If the
> {}-list is used as constructor arguments, the implementation is just
> as if you had used a ()-list. List elements are not copied except as
> by-value constructor arguments. 
> • If the {}-list is used to initialize
> the elements of an aggregate (an array or a class without a
> constructor), each list element initializes an element of the
> aggregate. List elements are not copied except as by-value arguments
> to aggregate element constructors. 
> • If the {}-list is used to
> construct an initializer_list object each list element is used to
> initialize an element of the underlying array of the initializer_list.
> Elements are typically copied from the initializer_list to wherever we
> use them.

The most popular use of {}-list seems to be *initializer_list*. In which, a temporary immutable is created, hence it is copy-initialized.

For constructor arguments and an aggregate, the book says the elements are **not** copied. How are these different than *initializer_list*?

What exactly does "List elements are not
copied except as by-value arguments to aggregate element constructors." mean? It seems contradictory.

Comment: Aggregate element is an element of aggregate, it can have a ctor? Also, whatever that source is, it uses different terminology from standard and apparently became even more confusing

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The C++ Programming Language(the book) is written by Stroustrup. I'm trying to learn C++ in more details.

Comment: If you have `class C { C(int, int); };` then `C c{1, 2};` is equivalent to `C c(1, 2);` - it just passes two arguments to the constructor. No initializer list is created. If you have `struct S{int x, y};` then `S s{1, 2};` directly initializes `s.x` with `1` and `s.y` with `2` - again, no initializer list here. `S` is an aggregate. Similar with `int arr[]{1, 2};`